# Typecasting in C not working (Attempting to convert number to ASCII represented letter)

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, printing, char

I'm currently have a pangram checker program set up, and I'm attempting to print out the characters the user did not enter (i.e the letters missing to make it a complete pangram). However, I'm trying to loop through 26 positions of the array (26 letters in the alphabet) and attempting to type cast the missing ones, but when I compile and run the program and when it goes to this case of not being a pangram, it proceeds to print "Letter wasn't typed" but it doesn't actually write out the letters that are missing! They don't appear at all! Any help would be much appreciated!

As always here is a snippet:

```
         for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
         {
             if (x[i] == 0)
             {
                 printf("%c\n letter wasn't typed!\n", (char)i);
 //Prints out "letter wasn't typed" without printing the actual letters that weren't typed by the user
                 getchar();
             }

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perhaps want

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
      if (x[i] == 0)
      {
          char base = 'A'; // or 'a'
          printf("%c\n letter wasn't typed!\n", (char)(i + base));
          //Prints out "letter wasn't typed" without printing the actual letters that weren't typed by the user
          getchar();
      }
}
```

You are printing lower range from letters where i is the code. (ASCII, EBCDIC etc)

These letters may or may not be printable. You perhaps want to print the roman letters (guessed from `26`) so you should add the base before printing.

Comment: Nothing appears to still show up :l(To clarify the base 'a' prints, but nothing else.

Comment: @user2084266 Try after removing `getchar();`

Comment: Cheers it works now! only thing is, how would i go about printing the missing letters in one line, instead of them all being looped one after the other?

Comment: Change inner printf to `printf("%c ", (char)(i + base));` and add another printf after loop `printf("letters weren't typed!\n");` If you want to put `getchar()`, add it after this `printf`.